# Как заменить некоторые элементы целочисленного массива на символы?

Tags: c++

Программа запрашивает два числа N и M, затем мы создаем двумерный массив и заполняем их числами. Программа в конце должна посчитать количество отрицательных чисел, и при выводе их заменить символом "х".

Задачу я решил, но вместо "x", я заменил нулем. Вопрос как заменить именно "x"- ом ? Мой код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен символьный массив, ведь `x` - символ. То есть используйте `char a[10][10]` сразу, либо преобразуйте к нему после вычислений.

А вообще, у вас же сказано **при выводе заменить**, т.е. заменять в исходном массиве не обязательно, достаточно проверять при выводе очередного элемента массива, является ли он отрицательным. Если да, то печатать `x`, иначе его самого.

Comment: Массив символов не нужен. Можно в массиве целых  присвоить элементу символ(у него есть целочисленное значение). Лучше оставьте вторую часть ответа

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ! Все работает (печатать x вместо отрицательного ).